# Set attribute value of angular directive from another controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Angular directive;

```
.directive('ngFilemanager', function () {
        return {
                    restrict: 'EA',
                    scope: {
                        thefilter: '=',
                    },
                    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                    },
                    templateUrl: '/templates/filemanager.html',
                    controller: FileManagerController
        }
```

Html:

```
<div id="testcontainer" ng-controller="OtherController">
    ...
    <div ng-click="vm.myfunction">Set Filter</div> 
    ...
        <div id="thefilemanager" ng-filemanager thefilter=""></div>
    ...
</div>
```

How can i set thefilter value in a function of `OtherController`?

I tried setting the attribute value by jquery but my ng-view isn't updated correctly then.

Comment: Assuming that you've tried `scope.thefilter = "value"`?

Comment: i need to change thefilter from another controller [updated question to make it clear]

Comment: The way you have configured (with `=`) means you want to map in a controller scoped property.  The controller that wraps the `div` can have property named `filter` and then, you would pass it in `theFilter`.  `thefilter="filter"`.  Then if you change in the directive the changes would be seen.

Comment: I have wrapped another controller (not FileManagerController) around the div. Setting `thefilter="myfilter"` in this does not work

Comment: the wrapping controller does not have the same scope as the directive?

Comment: as soon as you start throwing jQuery in to manipulate the DOM, have to use `$apply` to tell angular of changes...stay away from that route unless absolutely necessary ( usually it isn't)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got bi-directional isolated scope so:

```
function OtherController($scope){
  $scope.myfilter= "";
  $scope.setFilter = function(what){
    $scope.myfilter = what;
  }
}
```

and HTML:

```
<div id="testcontainer" ng-controller="OtherController">
   <div ng-click="setFilter('fun')">Set Filter</div> 
   <div id="thefilemanager" ng-filemanager thefilter="myfilter"></div>
</div>
```

Then when you change `$scope.myfilter` in the `OtherController`'s scope, `scope.thefilter` changes in your directive's scope.

If the "other" controller is not a direct parent, you could use $emit or $broadcast depending on where the target is.

Here's an example using $broadcast instead:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.setFilter = function(what){
    $scope.$broadcast('setFilter', what);
  }
});
```

then inside your directive you can listen:

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$on('setFilter', function(e, what){
      scope.thefilter = what;
    });
},
```

To make it work anywhere, you can $broadcast from $rootScope, but at that point you might want to re-evaluate why you have to do this. Angular itself does this a lot, for example, routeChangeSuccess event, but that doesn't mean you should do it.

Comment: what do you mean by *direct* parent?

Comment: I should say, a controller which shares scope with wherever the directive is. Which is usually the parent scope of your directive. In the example, by using ng-controller, we know the OtherController will be the parent scope. If you show me where the "OtherController" you speak of is, I can maybe help more.

Comment: And as other commenters have said, you shouldn't set the attribute via jQuery.

Comment: Well then you'll have to post a plnkr or a jsFiddle because you're doing something else wrong that we cannot see from the code provided.

Comment: Here is a Plnkr that shows it working just fine: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZfvPcDqOYKmRJ3JNPrjX of course I don't have your other controller or template or anything so I'm not sure what else could be wrong.

Comment: I have another controller wrapped around my directive (updated question). maybe this is the issue?

Comment: Yes, that is the issue. Everytime you create a controller you create a new scope. Now you're editing a variable in the wrong scope.

Comment: I added to this: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZfvPcDqOYKmRJ3JNPrjX so it will work like you want using $broadcast. There are other ways, but I think this is the simplest and it doesn't matter where your directive is as long as it's in a child scope somewhere.

Comment: One last thing... why do you set FileManagerController both in HTML via ng-controller and then once again in your directive? That seems a bit weird. Whatever you're doing there could probably be abstracted into a service which is injected into the directive.

Comment: I was just trying things. I removed it now.

Comment: I marked your answer correct. I think my issues are the typescript controller scopes.

Answer (score 0):

This will work if the other controller is a parent of `ngFilemanager`

```
<div id="thefilemanager" ng-filemanager thefilter="theFilterValue"></div>
```

In some other controller

```
...
$scope.theFilterValue = 'some other value';
...
```

Look the doc's [isolate scope on directives](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-custom-directives_demo_isolating-the-scope-of-a-directive) section