# D3 AngularJs Force Directed Graph

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I am trying to create a force directed graph but written in AngularJs instead. I have written my application in Angularjs but I am not understanding how to add my json to $scope.data, and anyway to write it more efficiently.

```
var app = angular.module("chartApp", []);
app.directive('graph', function() {
    var graphLink = function(scope, element) {
        var width = 960,
            height = 500;

        var color = d3.scale.category20();

        var force = d3.layout.force()
            .charge(-120)
            .linkDistance(30)
            .size([width, height]);

        var svg = d3.select(element[0]).append("svg") // attach d3 to directive element
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height);

        d3.json("js/miserables", function(error, graph) {
            if (error) throw error;

            force
                .nodes(graph.nodes)
                .links(graph.links)
                .start();

            var link = svg.selectAll(".link") // there might be a more angular way to do this...
                .data(graph.links)
                .enter().append("line")
                .attr("class", "link")
                .style("stroke-width", function (d) {
                    return Math.sqrt(d.value);
                });

            var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
                .data(graph.nodes)
                .enter().append("circle")
                .attr("class", "node")
                .attr("r", 5)
                .style("fill", function (d) {
                    return color(d.group);
                })
                .call(force.drag);

            node.append("title")
                .text(function (d) {
                    return d.name;
                });

            force.on("tick", function () {
                link.attr("x1", function (d) {
                    return d.source.x;
                })
                    .attr("y1", function (d) {
                        return d.source.y;
                    })
                    .attr("x2", function (d) {
                        return d.target.x;
                    })
                    .attr("y2", function (d) {
                        return d.target.y;
                    });

                node.attr("cx", function (d) {
                    return d.x;
                })
                    .attr("cy", function (d) {
                        return d.y;
                    });
            });

            return {
                link: graphLink, // pass in your link function here
                scope: {
                    data: '=' // pass in your data as an attribute
                              // this makes this reusable, and you can redraw if the data changes
                }
            };
        })}});
```

**json**

```
{
"nodes":[
{"name":"Myriel","group":1},
{"name":"Napoleon","group":1},
{"name":"Mlle.Baptistine","group":1},
{"name":"Mme.Magloire","group":1},
{"name":"CountessdeLo","group":1},
{"name":"Geborand","group":1},
{"name":"Champtercier","group":1},
{"name":"Cravatte","group":1},
{"name":"Count","group":1},
{"name":"OldMan","group":1},
{"name":"Labarre","group":2},
{"name":"Valjean","group":2},
{"name":"Marguerite","group":3},
{"name":"Mme.deR","group":2},
{"name":"Isabeau","group":2},
{"name":"Gervais","group":2},
{"name":"Tholomyes","group":3},
{"name":"Listolier","group":3},
{"name":"Fameuil","group":3},
{"name":"Blacheville","group":3},
{"name":"Favourite","group":3},
{"name":"Dahlia","group":3},
{"name":"Zephine","group":3},
{"name":"Fantine","group":3},
{"name":"Mme.Thenardier","group":4},
{"name":"Thenardier","group":4},
{"name":"Cosette","group":5},
{"name":"Javert","group":4},
{"name":"Fauchelevent","group":0},
{"name":"Bamatabois","group":2},
{"name":"Perpetue","group":3},
{"name":"Simplice","group":2},
{"name":"Scaufflaire","group":2},
{"name":"Woman1","group":2},
{"name":"Judge","group":2},
{"name":"Champmathieu","group":2},
{"name":"Brevet","group":2},
{"name":"Chenildieu","group":2},
{"name":"Cochepaille","group":2},
{"name":"Pontmercy","group":4},
{"name":"Boulatruelle","group":6},
{"name":"Eponine","group":4},
{"name":"Anzelma","group":4},
{"name":"Woman2","group":5},
{"name":"MotherInnocent","group":0},
{"name":"Gribier","group":0},
{"name":"Jondrette","group":7},
{"name":"Mme.Burgon","group":7},
{"name":"Gavroche","group":8},
{"name":"Gillenormand","group":5},
{"name":"Magnon","group":5},
{"name":"Mlle.Gillenormand","group":5},
{"name":"Mme.Pontmercy","group":5},
{"name":"Mlle.Vaubois","group":5},
{"name":"Lt.Gillenormand","group":5},
{"name":"Marius","group":8},
{"name":"BaronessT","group":5},
{"name":"Mabeuf","group":8},
{"name":"Enjolras","group":8},
{"name":"Combeferre","group":8},
{"name":"Prouvaire","group":8},
{"name":"Feuilly","group":8},
{"name":"Courfeyrac","group":8},
{"name":"Bahorel","group":8},
{"name":"Bossuet","group":8},
{"name":"Joly","group":8},
{"name":"Grantaire","group":8},
{"name":"MotherPlutarch","group":9},
{"name":"Gueulemer","group":4},
{"name":"Babet","group":4},
{"name":"Claquesous","group":4},
{"name":"Montparnasse","group":4},
{"name":"Toussaint","group":5},
{"name":"Child1","group":10},
{"name":"Child2","group":10},
{"name":"Brujon","group":4},
{"name":"Mme.Hucheloup","group":8}
],
"links":[
{"source":1,"target":0,"value":1},
{"source":2,"target":0,"value":8},
{"source":3,"target":0,"value":10},
{"source":3,"target":2,"value":6},
{"source":4,"target":0,"value":1},
{"source":5,"target":0,"value":1},
{"source":6,"target":0,"value":1},
{"source":7,"target":0,"value":1},
{"source":8,"target":0,"value":2},
{"source":9,"target":0,"value":1},
{"source":11,"target":10,"value":1},
{"source":11,"target":3,"value":3},
{"source":11,"target":2,"value":3},
{"source":11,"target":0,"value":5},
{"source":12,"target":11,"value":1},
{"source":13,"target":11,"value":1},
{"source":14,"target":11,"value":1},
{"source":15,"target":11,"value":1},
{"source":17,"target":16,"value":4},
{"source":18,"target":16,"value":4},
{"source":18,"target":17,"value":4},
{"source":19,"target":16,"value":4},
{"source":19,"target":17,"value":4},
{"source":19,"target":18,"value":4},
{"source":20,"target":16,"value":3},
{"source":20,"target":17,"value":3},
{"source":20,"target":18,"value":3},
{"source":20,"target":19,"value":4},
{"source":21,"target":16,"value":3},
{"source":21,"target":17,"value":3},
{"source":21,"target":18,"value":3},
{"source":21,"target":19,"value":3},
{"source":21,"target":20,"value":5},
{"source":22,"target":16,"value":3},
{"source":22,"target":17,"value":3},
{"source":22,"target":18,"value":3},
{"source":22,"target":19,"value":3},
{"source":22,"target":20,"value":4},
{"source":22,"target":21,"value":4},
{"source":23,"target":16,"value":3},
{"source":23,"target":17,"value":3},
{"source":23,"target":18,"value":3},
{"source":23,"target":19,"value":3},
{"source":23,"target":20,"value":4},
{"source":23,"target":21,"value":4},
{"source":23,"target":22,"value":4},
{"source":23,"target":12,"value":2},
{"source":23,"target":11,"value":9},
{"source":24,"target":23,"value":2},
{"source":24,"target":11,"value":7},
{"source":25,"target":24,"value":13},
{"source":25,"target":23,"value":1},
{"source":25,"target":11,"value":12},
{"source":26,"target":24,"value":4},
{"source":26,"target":11,"value":31},
{"source":26,"target":16,"value":1},
{"source":26,"target":25,"value":1},
{"source":27,"target":11,"value":17},
{"source":27,"target":23,"value":5},
{"source":27,"target":25,"value":5},
{"source":27,"target":24,"value":1},
{"source":27,"target":26,"value":1},
{"source":28,"target":11,"value":8},
{"source":28,"target":27,"value":1},
{"source":29,"target":23,"value":1},
{"source":29,"target":27,"value":1},
{"source":29,"target":11,"value":2},
{"source":30,"target":23,"value":1},
{"source":31,"target":30,"value":2},
{"source":31,"target":11,"value":3},
{"source":31,"target":23,"value":2},
{"source":31,"target":27,"value":1},
{"source":32,"target":11,"value":1},
{"source":33,"target":11,"value":2},
{"source":33,"target":27,"value":1},
{"source":34,"target":11,"value":3},
{"source":34,"target":29,"value":2},
{"source":35,"target":11,"value":3},
{"source":35,"target":34,"value":3},
{"source":35,"target":29,"value":2},
{"source":36,"target":34,"value":2},
{"source":36,"target":35,"value":2},
{"source":36,"target":11,"value":2},
{"source":36,"target":29,"value":1},
{"source":37,"target":34,"value":2},
{"source":37,"target":35,"value":2},
{"source":37,"target":36,"value":2},
{"source":37,"target":11,"value":2},
{"source":37,"target":29,"value":1},
{"source":38,"target":34,"value":2},
{"source":38,"target":35,"value":2},
{"source":38,"target":36,"value":2},
{"source":38,"target":37,"value":2},
{"source":38,"target":11,"value":2},
{"source":38,"target":29,"value":1},
{"source":39,"target":25,"value":1},
{"source":40,"target":25,"value":1},
{"source":41,"target":24,"value":2},
{"source":41,"target":25,"value":3},
{"source":42,"target":41,"value":2},
{"source":42,"target":25,"value":2},
{"source":42,"target":24,"value":1},
{"source":43,"target":11,"value":3},
{"source":43,"target":26,"value":1},
{"source":43,"target":27,"value":1},
{"source":44,"target":28,"value":3},
{"source":44,"target":11,"value":1},
{"source":45,"target":28,"value":2},
{"source":47,"target":46,"value":1},
{"source":48,"target":47,"value":2},
{"source":48,"target":25,"value":1},
{"source":48,"target":27,"value":1},
{"source":48,"target":11,"value":1},
{"source":49,"target":26,"value":3},
{"source":49,"target":11,"value":2},
{"source":50,"target":49,"value":1},
{"source":50,"target":24,"value":1},
{"source":51,"target":49,"value":9},
{"source":51,"target":26,"value":2},
{"source":51,"target":11,"value":2},
{"source":52,"target":51,"value":1},
{"source":52,"target":39,"value":1},
{"source":53,"target":51,"value":1},
{"source":54,"target":51,"value":2},
{"source":54,"target":49,"value":1},
{"source":54,"target":26,"value":1},
{"source":55,"target":51,"value":6},
{"source":55,"target":49,"value":12},
{"source":55,"target":39,"value":1},
{"source":55,"target":54,"value":1},
{"source":55,"target":26,"value":21},
{"source":55,"target":11,"value":19},
{"source":55,"target":16,"value":1},
{"source":55,"target":25,"value":2},
{"source":55,"target":41,"value":5},
{"source":55,"target":48,"value":4},
{"source":56,"target":49,"value":1},
{"source":56,"target":55,"value":1},
{"source":57,"target":55,"value":1},
{"source":57,"target":41,"value":1},
{"source":57,"target":48,"value":1},
{"source":58,"target":55,"value":7},
{"source":58,"target":48,"value":7},
{"source":58,"target":27,"value":6},
{"source":58,"target":57,"value":1},
{"source":58,"target":11,"value":4},
{"source":59,"target":58,"value":15},
{"source":59,"target":55,"value":5},
{"source":59,"target":48,"value":6},
{"source":59,"target":57,"value":2},
{"source":60,"target":48,"value":1},
{"source":60,"target":58,"value":4},
{"source":60,"target":59,"value":2},
{"source":61,"target":48,"value":2},
{"source":61,"target":58,"value":6},
{"source":61,"target":60,"value":2},
{"source":61,"target":59,"value":5},
{"source":61,"target":57,"value":1},
{"source":61,"target":55,"value":1},
{"source":62,"target":55,"value":9},
{"source":62,"target":58,"value":17},
{"source":62,"target":59,"value":13},
{"source":62,"target":48,"value":7},
{"source":62,"target":57,"value":2},
{"source":62,"target":41,"value":1},
{"source":62,"target":61,"value":6},
{"source":62,"target":60,"value":3},
{"source":63,"target":59,"value":5},
{"source":63,"target":48,"value":5},
{"source":63,"target":62,"value":6},
{"source":63,"target":57,"value":2},
{"source":63,"target":58,"value":4},
{"source":63,"target":61,"value":3},
{"source":63,"target":60,"value":2},
{"source":63,"target":55,"value":1},
{"source":64,"target":55,"value":5},
{"source":64,"target":62,"value":12},
{"source":64,"target":48,"value":5},
{"source":64,"target":63,"value":4},
{"source":64,"target":58,"value":10},
{"source":64,"target":61,"value":6},
{"source":64,"target":60,"value":2},
{"source":64,"target":59,"value":9},
{"source":64,"target":57,"value":1},
{"source":64,"target":11,"value":1},
{"source":65,"target":63,"value":5},
{"source":65,"target":64,"value":7},
{"source":65,"target":48,"value":3},
{"source":65,"target":62,"value":5},
{"source":65,"target":58,"value":5},
{"source":65,"target":61,"value":5},
{"source":65,"target":60,"value":2},
{"source":65,"target":59,"value":5},
{"source":65,"target":57,"value":1},
{"source":65,"target":55,"value":2},
{"source":66,"target":64,"value":3},
{"source":66,"target":58,"value":3},
{"source":66,"target":59,"value":1},
{"source":66,"target":62,"value":2},
{"source":66,"target":65,"value":2},
{"source":66,"target":48,"value":1},
{"source":66,"target":63,"value":1},
{"source":66,"target":61,"value":1},
{"source":66,"target":60,"value":1},
{"source":67,"target":57,"value":3},
{"source":68,"target":25,"value":5},
{"source":68,"target":11,"value":1},
{"source":68,"target":24,"value":1},
{"source":68,"target":27,"value":1},
{"source":68,"target":48,"value":1},
{"source":68,"target":41,"value":1},
{"source":69,"target":25,"value":6},
{"source":69,"target":68,"value":6},
{"source":69,"target":11,"value":1},
{"source":69,"target":24,"value":1},
{"source":69,"target":27,"value":2},
{"source":69,"target":48,"value":1},
{"source":69,"target":41,"value":1},
{"source":70,"target":25,"value":4},
{"source":70,"target":69,"value":4},
{"source":70,"target":68,"value":4},
{"source":70,"target":11,"value":1},
{"source":70,"target":24,"value":1},
{"source":70,"target":27,"value":1},
{"source":70,"target":41,"value":1},
{"source":70,"target":58,"value":1},
{"source":71,"target":27,"value":1},
{"source":71,"target":69,"value":2},
{"source":71,"target":68,"value":2},
{"source":71,"target":70,"value":2},
{"source":71,"target":11,"value":1},
{"source":71,"target":48,"value":1},
{"source":71,"target":41,"value":1},
{"source":71,"target":25,"value":1},
{"source":72,"target":26,"value":2},
{"source":72,"target":27,"value":1},
{"source":72,"target":11,"value":1},
{"source":73,"target":48,"value":2},
{"source":74,"target":48,"value":2},
{"source":74,"target":73,"value":3},
{"source":75,"target":69,"value":3},
{"source":75,"target":68,"value":3},
{"source":75,"target":25,"value":3},
{"source":75,"target":48,"value":1},
{"source":75,"target":41,"value":1},
{"source":75,"target":70,"value":1},
{"source":75,"target":71,"value":1},
{"source":76,"target":64,"value":1},
{"source":76,"target":65,"value":1},
{"source":76,"target":66,"value":1},
{"source":76,"target":63,"value":1},
{"source":76,"target":62,"value":1},
{"source":76,"target":48,"value":1},
{"source":76,"target":58,"value":1}
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d3.json("myGraph.json", function(error, **json**) {
    if (error) throw error;
}
```

Means read file *myGraph.json*, and now all data from *myGraph.json* in your **json**

Now you can write:

```
$scope.data = null;
//you should initialize variable before your function!
var graphLink = function(scope, element) {
  d3.json("myGraph.json", function(error, **json**) {
        if (error) throw error;
        $scope.data = json;
        console.log($scope.data);
    }
}
```

Comment: do you mind by showing inserting the code you wrote with mine?

Comment: I used your code with my to show you easiest way to understand  answer to your question.

Comment: I have been trying this with no success... jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You should not load your json inside the directive. Your directive has an isolated scope and that scope has an attribute (data).

You should load your json in the app controller and pass it to your directive data. After that, in your directive you watch for data changes and re-draw the graph if the data changes. Therefore, your graph directive will be reusable and you can have multi graph in your application.

Comment: see this one:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20524773/set-attribute-value-of-angular-directive-from-another-controller

Comment: You can look at your directive as a blackbox (it applies only to reusable directives not all of them). You put the data as input and your directive draws it. It should not have any business with the data. Controller is the place where you load data and pass it to directive